# Free DNS redirect for non-static IP with purchased domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, ip, forwarding

I purchased a domain name from GoDaddy, and I'm wondering if there is a free way to create a DNS redirect to my home apache2 server (Ubuntu). I don't have a business line, so I technically don't have a static ip.

Right now I'm using no-ip with one of their free (sub)domain redirects/forwards, but I want my new domain linked. The only way I know is to use no-ip's $25/yr advanced service. I know that's not a lot considering... just curious if other options exist out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure your own domain using free DNS services like. 
http://freedns.afraid.org/

For using them you will need to change the name servers in godaddy to point to afraid.org's DNS servers. Signup and use one of these clients to routinely update your dynamic IP in afraid.org's DNS address.

http://freedns.afraid.org/scripts/freedns.clients.php

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Looks to be working. Thanks so much!